# How can I create an array using variables in MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have this and it works, but only if I use Dev C++. It doesn't compile when I try to in MSVC.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;


int main() {

 int x=0, y=0;
 cout << "Dame un numero\n";
 cin >> x;

 cout << "Dame otro numero\n";
 cin >> y;
 int figura[x][y];
```

When I get to that last line in MSVC, it says that the expresion (x and y) must have a constant value. But I want the user to input the size of array they like to use.

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: You want *variable length arrays*, which is not supported in C++.  Some compilers may add the feature as an extension.

Comment: You could allocate a block in dynamic memory: `int * p_figure = new int[x * y];`